# How to uses already initialized class in another View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, class, uiviewcontroller

I am making an iOS app with multiple tab views. Two of the views use the same view controller so therefore they both have an instance. I wanted to know if it was possible to use only one instance of the view controller for two views. The reason i want to do this is because i have a "Connect" and "Disconnect" button on one view that uses the GameKit peer picker and i have "Send File" on another view that has to use the session that i created from the other view with the connect button.

Answer (score 0):

In any viewController which belongs to the tabBarController:

```
UIViewController *vc1 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
MyCustomClass *sharedObject = [vc1 theObject];
UIViewController *vc2 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[vc2 setTheObject:sharedObject];
```

You should have set @property for the "theObject" for both view controllers

Comment: Hi so in my tab bar controller.m or .h do i add the code above

Comment: No you do not add code on the tabBarController. You add code to UIVIewController subclass

Comment: Hi if you can please explain what i should do, i have tried everything with no success. What method or function do i post the above in also?